# I keep getting an error on RedLaser app for iPod Touch 4th generation. How to fix?

Tags: ios, applications, ipod-touch, error, third-party

I just downloaded the RedLaser app from the App Store on my iPod touch 4th generation, 6.1.3.  If I go to launch the app, it goes to the Scan section and works normally for about 5 seconds.  Then, no matter what I'm doing within the app, I get this error.  Please see the screenshot here:

[image]

Plus, whenever I tap "OK", the error comes back.  It won't go away at all.
So, how can I fix this error so it goes away and doesn't come back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kCLErrorDomain is error reporting regarding the OS framework "Core Location." See [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/CoreLocationConstantsRef.pdf) for more info (written for OS X, which iOS is based upon).

So, for troubleshooting, I'd check your location services, maybe disable them/re-enable them and relaunch the app.

If that doesn't work, try re-downloading the app.

If the issue persists after a reinstallation of the app, the next step I would try would be to [restore your device](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414).

Comment: Since I don't have enough reputation, it wouldn't let me post the following: If the issue persists after setting your device up as new, time to visit the Genius Bar.  See here for instructions on how to set up an iOS device as "new": http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4137

Comment: I turned off Location Services for the app and I am no longer getting the error.  Thanks!